# Renaming all file in a directory older then 1 day

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I want to rename all file in a specified folder ending with .txt to .csv that are older then 1 day. I have the following that will get me all files ending with .txt and rename them to .csv

```
For /R %1 %%G IN (*.txt) DO ren "%%G" "%%~nG.csv"
```

The part I am struggling with is only renaming the files that are older then a day. I am looking for a solution that will work despite the date format that may be set up on a system.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710628/forfiles-delete-all-files-older-than-1-day-24hours-using-creation-date - There are details there for deleting files older than a day, you should be able to rework that to run your code to rename them instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forfiles`, which is a native command since Windows Vista.

> ### Forfiles
>
> Selects and executes a command on a file or set of files. This command is useful for batch processing.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `/p <Path>`
> Specifies the path from which to start the search. By default, searching starts in the current working directory.
>
> `/m <SearchMask>`
> Searches files according to the specified search mask. The default search mask is `*.*`.
>
> `/s`
> Instructs the **forfiles** command to search into subdirectories recursively.
>
> `/c "<Command>"`
>
> Runs the specified command on each file. Command strings should be enclosed in quotation marks. The default command is **"cmd /c echo @file"**.
>
> `/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]`
>
> Selects files with a last modified date within the specified time frame.
>
> <sub>Source: [Forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx)</sub>

### Example usage

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in (
'forfiles /p %1 /m *.txt /s /c "cmd /c echo @path" /d -1'
) do ren "%%~G" "%%~nG.csv"
```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)